# Mouse input problems in java

Tags: java, swing, timer, mouse

**Edit:**
I have an application that uses a swing Timer to control when an action listener interface fires. The mouse logic works but occasionally will not detect a click. Below is my commented code.

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{
    private MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
    private static String State; /*Makes the control flow simpler, just checking 
    strings that describe the state. All the states are contained in GameState class.*/
    public Board()
    {

        this.addMouseListener(this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);

        mainMenu.initLogIn(); /*This just loads the button images*/
        Timer timer = new Timer(12, this); /*(millisecond delay, tells this class 
        to update any actionlistener (mouselistener etc)*/
        timer.start();
    }


    public void paint(Graphics G)
    {
        super.paint(G);
        Graphics G2d = (Graphics2D)G; 
        /*Main menu paint logic*/

            //          This paints buttons from mainMenu class on screen
            G.drawImage(mainMenu.getTopic1().getspriteImage(),
                    mainMenu.getTopic1().getxCoord(), 
                    mainMenu.getTopic1().getyCoord(),this);
            G.drawImage(mainMenu.getTopic2().getspriteImage(),
                    mainMenu.getTopic2().getxCoord(),
                    mainMenu.getTopic2().getyCoord(), this);
            G.drawImage(mainMenu.getTopic3().getspriteImage(),
                    mainMenu.getTopic3().getxCoord(),
                    mainMenu.getTopic3().getyCoord(),this);
            /*Shows mouse input worked by changing the background color*/
            if (State == GameState.MAINMENU_TOPIC1)
            {
                setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            if (State == GameState.MAINMENU_TOPIC2)
            {
                setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            }
            if (State == GameState.MAINMENU_TOPIC3)
            {
                setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            }
            repaint(); //tells paint to repaint, which allows gui to update

    }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            Point point = e.getPoint();
            /*This contains the logic to change State based on mouse clicks*/

                if(mainMenu.getTopic1().getRectangle().contains(point))
                {
                    State = GameState.MAINMENU_TOPIC1;
                }
                if(mainMenu.getTopic2().getRectangle().contains(point))
                {
                    State = GameState.MAINMENU_TOPIC2;
                }
                if(mainMenu.getTopic3().getRectangle().contains(point))
                {
                    State = GameState.MAINMENU_TOPIC3;
                }
        }
```

So, I am unsure why mouse clicks would not always be detected. I know there is a chance that the time allocated to update the action listeners could be too short. However, there is not very much code for the machine to loop through, so I figure this is not the problem. Any thoughts on what might cause the mouse to behave this way?

Also, I will definitely implement this later using JButtons. I am sure that would help clean up my code on the larger project

Thanks for the comments, and I hope this clears up the majority of the questions.

Comment: `"This loops between my mouse logic, actionPerformed, and paint methods (if I understand this correctly)."` -- this is strange and confusing to me. If you don't get an answer soon, or even if you do, please explain what your program is doing in greater detail and just what your problem is.

Comment: `new Timer(1, this);` -- also this is a bit unrealistic in that you'll never seen 1000 fps. Perhaps 12-14 msec is more realistic.

Comment: Can you define 'skip a click'? Do you mean does not respond to every click? The Timer is quite fast (every millisecond?), and with the code posted can't really even try to reproduce or let alone guess at the problem. Recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also your huge switchboard MouseListener looks nightmarish (sorry for being blunt, but I have to call it as I see it). why not simply use individual ActionListeners on JButtons?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will definitely expand on what the program is doing, probably through an MVCE as copeg suggested. Also no need to apologize, I always appreciate constructive criticism. I'm fairly new to programming so I will take all the help I can get!

Comment: As an aside, I wonder if you would be better off swapping JPanels with a CardLayout, each JPanel drawing a different background and having different behaviors, rather than swapping images as you're doing. I'd certainly recommend going this route if you are displaying views with vastly different behaviors, such as a menu JPanel and a game play JPanel.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I will definitely look into it. I am currently playing with the JPanels and letting JButton handle the action event listeners. However, you are describing my situation perfectly as the views do have _very_ different behavior. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mouse "click" may essentially be a double or triple click. You can get that by using `evt.clickCount`. It will coalite as one event.

If you want to get every "press", use `mousePressed()` instead.

Comment: You are correct, I gathered the mouseclicks and when the skip would occur it would quickly flash the number two and revert to a one. When I used the mouse pressed this problem was fixed. I noticed most applications will require an actual "click" to get the button to do its function. So the click will cause the button to depress, and if you drag the mouse off while still click the button will not respond. Does this mean my best option to get a click to work as I described would be to have logic in both the pressed and released methods?